# Disable light sensor of Webcam which lights up LED

Tags: laptop, webcam, led, sensors

I use an external webcam with pre-built LED lights which light up in low-light situations. The light sensor is on the top of the webcam.

The software supplied with the webcam doesn't have a function to disable the functions of LED. Is there any other way to do it?

I'm posting a pic of the webcam - [Frontech jil 2243](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70slr.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a way to do this, other than physically disconnecting the internal wirings that power up the said LEDs (infrared). This particular webcam doesn't look sophisticated enough to offer such feature.

Comment: Ya it's cheap one I am using for a project. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @borb183 That's what's nice about it - if you break it, just buy another one :)

Comment: Haha that's true